# Positioning with CSS

Tags: html, css

The solution to this problem is probably extremely easy, but I've been struggling with it for a while an I just cannot get it working.
I want to have 2 divs of different sizes aligned next to each other. Problem is that if I put any text into the first div, the other one is moved a few lines down.

The simplified version of the problem would look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
        <div style="background:red; display:inline-block; height:100%; width:50%;">
            aaa<br>
            aaa<br>
            aaa<br>
            aaa<br>
        </div>
        <div style="background:green; display:inline-block; height:5em; width:5em;">
            bbb
        </div>
        <div>
    </body>
</html>
```

also, I'd rather not use the "position" property as I cannot predict the size of the "bbb" div and I want to put some more small divs under the "bbb"

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle or pen at codepen.io

Comment: as best practice: you should separate the styling from the markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` - See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b3LUZ/1/

Also, you have no closing tag for your first `<div>`, just another opening one.

Comment: as best practice: you should separate the styling from the markup.

Comment: @avrahamcool, I assumed OP had just done this for a simplified question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in you code.. There's a wrong-typed closing tag.. Should be `</div>`, not `<div>`.

However, I'd prefer using float css property set to "left" for both containers rather than `display: inline-block`.

After your divs you could put a div with "clear" css property set to "both". like this:

```
    <div style="background:red; float:left; height:100%; width:50%;">
        aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
    </div>
    <div style="background:green; float:left; height:5em; width:5em;">
        bbb
    </div>
    <div style="height: 0; width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "`float:left`" property instead of "`display:inline-block`"

Please see the code below:

```
<div>
    <div style="background:red; float:left; height:100%; width:50%;">
        aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
        aaa<br>
    </div>
    <div style="background:green; float:left; height:5em; width:5em;">
        bbb
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <p>To make sure rest of the content doesn't float and rather comes below these divs, give clear:"both" class after floating divs</p>
<div>
```

You can refer to the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/eyrAn/

Please let me know if this resolves your issue.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

try this **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/9wrz6/)**

HTML

```
    <div>
        <div class="first">
            aaa<br>
            aaa<br>
            aaa<br>
            aaa<br>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            bbb
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.first{
    background:red;
    display:inline-block; 
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
}
.second{
    background:green; 
    display:inline-block;
    height:5em; 
    width:5em;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```